# Object conditional not being detected in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, conditional-statements

I have the following code to add up all the sum of the numbers in the object:

```
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: [1,2,3,4, [5,6,7]],
  d: {
    e: 1,
    f: 2,
  }
}


function sum(obj) {
  let res = 0;
  for(let key in obj) {
    const val = obj[key];
    if(typeof val === 'object' && !Array.isArray(val)) {
      res = res + sum(val);
    }
    if(Array.isArray(val)) {
      res = res + flattenArray(val);
    }
    else {
      //console.log(val)
      res = res + val;
    }
  }

  return res;
}

function flattenArray(arr) {
  let sum = 0;
  
  for(let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    const item = arr[i];

    if(!Array.isArray(item)) {
      sum = sum + item;
    } else {
      sum = sum + flattenArray(item);
    }
  }

  return sum; //34
}

sum(obj);
```

In this function, the sum returns `34[object Object]`. So 34 is the correct answer, but I'm a little confused on why it has the string `[object Object]` here.

I went through my code and I see that at this line:

```
//console.log(val)
```

val is actually an object: `{ e: 1, f: 2 }`. However, why was it not caught by this condition:
`if(typeof val === 'object' && !Array.isArray(val))` and go also into the `else` condition?

Comment: You have an `if {} if {} else {}` chain.  Please focus on that.

Comment: You most likely intended to have an `if {} else if {} else {}` chain

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten the array using a recursive function with `Object.values()`, and `Array.flatMap)`, and sum the flattened array using `Array.reduce()`:

```js
const deepFlatten = obj =>
  Object.values(obj)
    .flatMap(o => typeof o === 'object' ? deepFlatten(o) : o)
    
const sum = arr => arr.reduce((s, n) => s + n, 0)

const obj = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":[1,2,3,4,[5,6,7]],"d":{"e":1,"f":2}}

const result = sum(deepFlatten(obj))

console.log(result)
```

The problem in the `sum` function is that you don't have an `else` between the 1st and 2nd/3rd cases, which means that object can be handled by the 1st `if`, and then by the 2nd `if` or it's attached `else`.

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: [1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6, 7]],
  d: {
    e: 1,
    f: 2,
  }
}

function sum(obj) {
  let res = 0;
  for (let key in obj) {
    const val = obj[key];
    if (typeof val === 'object' && !Array.isArray(val)) {
      res = res + sum(val);
       // the missing else
    } else if (Array.isArray(val)) {
      res = res + flattenArray(val);
    } else {
      res = res + val;
    }
  }

  return res;
}

function flattenArray(arr) {
  let sum = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const item = arr[i];

    if (!Array.isArray(item)) {
      sum = sum + item;
    } else {
      sum = sum + flattenArray(item);
    }
  }

  return sum; //34
}

const result = sum(obj);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi there! So here's what I don't understand, in my original code, what does the `else` case apply to? I thought `else` would be a catch-all case for anything that isn't part of the other 2 ifs. So I thought it meant to say, `if it's not an object` (first case), or `it's not an array`, then go into this `else` condition

Comment: When you have multiple `if` clauses, of which you want only one case to be applied, you need to chain them with `else`. When one of the ifs is `true`, it will be applied, and the chain will end. If you don't use `else`, every condition is checked, and applied if it's `true`. In your case the 2nd and 3rd clauses are chained with `else`, so if it the 2nd is `false` the 3rd would be applied. The 1st is not connected, and even if it's `true`, and the 2nd/3rd would be checked as well.

Comment: This is [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/conditionals#else_if) can help you.

Comment: Oh so `else` will only be applied to the `if` condition immediately preceding it, unless we use `else if`?

Comment: If you have multiple `if` clauses, and you want to stop as soon as one is `true`, you'll have to chain them with `else if`. The last `else` is the fallback - when no if is `true`. And yes, the `else` only refers to the `if` preceding it.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now. I have a question about your `Array.flatmap`. I just read on it, but still don't understand exactly what this line does `.flatMap(o => typeof o === 'object' ? deepFlatten(o) : o)`. Could you help me explain what this is mapping/ doing under the hood?

Comment: If the type of the `o` is an object (arrays count as well), call `deepFlatten` on it, so it would be flattened as well. If not just return `o`. Calling a function from within is called recursion. The idea is that `deepFlatten` iterates the object/array properties, if any of them is an object/array it will be flattened by `deepFlatten` as well, and so on. Whenever a primitive is found, it will be returned as is (this is the stop condition of the recursion). Using `Array.flatMap()` will flatten all resulting arrays into a single array.